# I have a problem with a code rendering a recursive tree with iteration in draw function in Javascript p5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I have the below code rendering a set of trees, The problem with this code is it includes noLoop. if noLoop is removed, the trees keep pulsing and generating new trees. I need to move this tree function to another long code, which is actually a game with a lot of objects in it. The noLoop in this function stop everything else in my draw function.  and I wasn't able to restructure the code to make part of it in the setup.

The code below :

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  background(200);
}

function draw() {
  noLoop(); // NoLoop must be in draw in order for the code tho work

  branchIteration(width / 2, height / 4);
}

function branch(len, firstTime = false, x, y) {
  translate(x, y);
  if (firstTime) {
    translate(width / 2, height / 2);
    firstTime = true;
  }

  angleMode(DEGREES);
  push();
  if (len > 10) {
    strokeWeight(map(len, 10, 100, 1, 15));
    stroke(70, 40, 20);
    line(0, 0, 0, -len);

    translate(0, -len);
    rotate(random(-20, -30));
    console.log(random(-20, -30));
    branch(len * random(0.7, 0.9), 0, 0 - len);
    rotate(random(50, 60));
    branch(len * random(0.7, 0.9), 0, 0 - len);
  } else {
    var r = 80 + random(-20, 20);
    var g = 120 + random(-20, 20);
    var b = 40 + random(-20, 20);
    fill(r, g, b, 150);
    noStroke();
    ellipse(0, 0, 10);
    beginShape();
    for (var i = 135; i > 40; i--) {
      var rad = 15;
      var x = rad * cos(i);
      var y = rad * sin(-i) + 20;
      vertex(x, y);
    }
    endShape(CLOSE);
  }
  pop();
}

function branchIteration(xPos, yPos) {
  for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    push();
    var xPosOffset = -2000 + j * 350;
    translate(xPos + xPosOffset, yPos);
    branch(60, true);
    pop();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.5.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Link to try the code https://editor.p5js.org/josefalk/sketches/taCAyFI4X

I want noLoop removed from draw.

Others advised me to place the function in setup. I cannot load this function in the setup, Because I'm doing a transformation in the destination code draw function and I want trees to move with other objects. as below:

Draw ();

push(); translate(-cameraPosX * 0.2, 0);

function mountain

function clouds

some other functions

tree code function here // **which I cannot add**

pop(); // transform end status.

I want noLoop removed

I don't want to use conditional statements. e.g if (!branchesDrawn) {branchIteration(width / 2, height / 4); branchesDrawn = true; }

because it disappears quickly because other items render on top of it.

I tried also importing values from the setup function, but It did not work.

I need:

1. re-structure the code without noLoop and the program loading the same set of tree every frame. When you re-load the page new trees will be generated.
2. In the code, you see a lone logging random value to the console : console.log (random (-20, -30)) . The console is logging a lot of random value lines then it stop. even it has noLoop in it. But if you place the same random console logging in setup, You will only get one line random value. why the random value generating few more number in draw but it generate only one number in setup? I'm missing some knowledge here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research, I found the solution.
Which is to create an array of layers. I called it branchLayer. I declared it as an empty array. I passed a parameter called "z" to the branch function. I edit all the function content to pass "z" value as the array index.

Through this I got the below things achieved:

1. The amount of trees is not static, which means I can add as many
   trees as I want. It tree does not loop (no noLoop() required).
2. It does not affect any other lines in the draw function.
3. If I'm drawing off the screen, I can render only what is on the screen. I  don't need to render all the trees in advance because the render is
   called through the condition.

The result is in the code below.
Thank you all for participating in my question.

```
let branchLayer;
function setup() 
{
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  branchLayer = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    branchLayer[i] = createGraphics(220,200, P2D);
    //branchLayer[i].background (180);
    branch (35, 0,-20, i, true);
    console.log ("test");
  }
  
}
function draw() 
{
  background(220);
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    image(branchLayer[i], 250*i, 0);
    image(branchLayer[i], 250*i, 200);
  }

}
function branch (len, x,y,z, firstTime=false) // define a function named branch with parameters :
                                              //len (Tree size), firstTime (first time translate), x, and y
{
    //branchLayer[z].translate (x,y); // move the origin to the given x and y position
    if (firstTime) // check if this is the first time calling the function
    {
        branchLayer[z].translate (branchLayer[z].width / 2 , branchLayer[z].height); // move the origin to the center of the canvas
        firstTime = true; // set firstTime to true
    }
    
    branchLayer[z].angleMode(DEGREES); // set the angle mode to degrees
    branchLayer[z].push (); // save the current transformation state
    if (len > 10) // check if the length is greater than 10
    {   
        branchLayer[z].strokeWeight (map(len, 10, 100, 1, 15)); // set the stroke weight based on the length of the branch
        branchLayer[z].stroke (70, 40, 20); // set the stroke color
        branchLayer[z].line (0,0,0, -len); // draw a line from the origin to the top of the branch
        
        branchLayer[z].translate (0, -len); // move the origin to the top of the branch
        branchLayer[z].rotate (random (-20, -30)); // rotate the canvas by a random angle
        branch (len * random(0.7, 0.9), 0, 0 -len, z); // call the branch function recursively with a shorter length and a new x position
        branchLayer[z].rotate (random (50, 60)); // rotate the canvas by another random angle
        branch (len * random(0.7, 0.9), 0, 0 -len, z); // call the branch function recursively with a shorter length and a new x position
    }
    else // if the length is less than or equal to 10
    {
        var r = 80 + random (-20, 20); // generate a random red color value
        var g = 120 + random (-20, 20); // generate a random green color value
        var b = 40 + random (-20, 20); // generate a random blue color value
        branchLayer[z].fill (r, g, b, 150); // set the fill color with a slightly transparent alpha value
        branchLayer[z].noStroke(); // remove the stroke
        branchLayer[z].ellipse (0, 0, 10); // draw a circle at the origin
        branchLayer[z].beginShape (); // begin drawing a shape
        for (var i = 135; i > 40; i--) // iterate over a range of angles
        {
            var rad = 15; // set the radius of the curve
            var x = rad * cos (i); // calculate the x position of the point on the curve
            var y = rad * sin (-i) +20; // calculate the y position of the point on the curve vertex
            branchLayer[z].vertex (x,y);
        }
       branchLayer[z].endShape (CLOSE);
    }
  branchLayer[z].pop ();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Trees are random, so every time you generate one it will look different.

One option is to include a `randomSeed(42)` at the beginning of your draw function, so everytime trees are generated they will look the same. (you can put any number, 42 is just an example)

```
function draw() {
  randomSeed(42);   
  branchIteration(width / 2, height / 4);
}
```

However trees are expensive to generate (specially if your recursion goes very deep), so I'd instead generate them once, then use `saveCanvas()`  to save the current canvas as an image and then use that image in the draw function.

If redrawing your background at every frame drops your fps there are other techniques to only update a desired part of the image and leave the rest of the background static.

Take a look at the library https://osteele.github.io/p5.libs/p5.layers/  that includes a lot of useful tools for drawing at different layers, so you can leave some layers static and only update other layers, making your program performance increase.

Finally, I'd recommend you start using classes, so your code gets more organized. Make a class `Tree` and put it in a different file, so your main file keeps as simple and clean as possible. That's important as you will start adding more and more things, and keeping things encapsulated in classes is a very good idea.

Comment: Thank you. Can you guide me on how to do it through saveCanvas() function?
Because I added a new function, I included 
var tree = createCanvas(1000,1000); 
  saveCanvas (tree, "myTree"); 
randomSeed(42);   
  branchIteration(width / 2, height / 4);
canvas.restore (); 

I Called it in setup, It does not draw it gives me pop-up window to save the file.

Or maybe you can write the code and I will learn from it. Thank you.

Comment: I can't use the external library because I'm studying and other libraries are not included in my current course. Thanks again.  @sembei Norimaki.

Comment: The randomSeed(42); function worked, But it made my game very slow It is very expensive with such a recursive tree and consumes the hardware.

Comment: The canvas needs to be large as -2000 , 2000

Comment: The idea about saving the canvas as an image is that you execute your code once to generate the trees and then save the canvas inside an image manually. Then your real code will no longer generate the trees but instead use the image that you generated previously. Otherwise generating the trees over and over again will be very costly. You can try reducing the fps with `frameRate(10)`. This will only refresh your screen 10 times per second. You mentioned you want to add something else and that's why you need to loop. Could you provide further code about what you want to do?

Comment: In this case, this is a limitation of p5.js. I don't get why it can't be possible to render the trees only one time and get them fixed on the screen without rendering them every frame. Because the idea of reducing the frame size is also a limitation. If reducing the frame rate worked, it will limit how much more I can add to my code. 

Saving it as an image is not a solution, I can change the scale, and size, and the program can't fit to window size and a lot more.

If converting stuff to photos is accepted, I could convert everything like that.

Comment: You can make your own implementation of layers without an external package by having multiple p5 canvases on top of each other with absolute positioning.

Comment: The canvas is just a bunch of pixels.  If you have other content on top of the tree then those tree pixels have been changed.  Think of it like MS Paint.  If your code only adds to the canvas and never removes anything then this is fine.  If you want to have a character in front of the tree in one frame and move the character in the next frame then you cannot have both things in the same canvas without redrawing the tree.  Because the portion that was behind the character has been lost.  You must either redraw the tree or keep them in separate canvases so that the tree is preserved.

Comment: You might be able to use `ctx.save()` and `ctx.restore()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Basic_animations